# Deployment of Rails app with nginx and mongrel cluster on ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, mongrel

I installed mongrel cluster and nginx module for it on to my virtual machine. 
The working environment is

```
ruby 1.9.2
rails 3.0.6
rubygems 1.7.2
mongrel_cluster 1.0.5
mongrel 1.2
```

When I start the mongrel cluster, it throws me the following error.
The application is off line
Please suggest me some solution. I have tried lot many googled solutions and none of them fixed the issue. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
*starting port 8011
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems called from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gem_plugin-0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:109
.
NOTE: from_installed_gems(arg) is deprecated. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in deprecate'
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in called from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:50
.
** !!! PID file tmp/pids/mongrel.8011.pid already exists.  Mongrel could be running already.  Check your log/mongrel.8011.log for errors.
** !!! Exiting with error.  You must stop mongrel and clear the .pid before I'll attempt a start.*
```

EDIT:

Thank you @dioms and @Hmallett. I updated the gems and deleted the already existing pid files from tmp/pids and restarted d cluster. It gave me d error

```
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems called from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gem_plugin-0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:109
.
NOTE: from_installed_gems(arg) is deprecated. From /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in deprecate'
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in called from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb:50
.
starting port 8009
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems called from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/gem_plugin-0.2.3/lib/gem_plugin.rb:109
```

Please suggest me some solution to  it. I am a newbie to the server installations and I am not sure what exactly to include in the configuration script.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some of your gems are deprecated

Try this to update them

`gem update && gem update --system`

Answer (score 0):

Does tmp/pids/mongrel.8011.pid exist?

Are you sure a mongrel is not already running and listening on port 8011?

If so, rm tmp/pids/mogrel.8011.pid and try restarting.

The deprecated gem warning is just a warning, the last two lines are the clue why it doesn't start.

Also, it looks like you're running Ruby 1.9.1, but I think rails 3 needs 1.9.2 if you want to use ruby 1.9.